# "error": "invalid_client" from custom OWIN implementation

Tags: owin, asp.net-web-api2

I am implementing OWIN authentication on a mysql backend, I dont thnk thats a problem as my registration work pretty well. I have basically worked off [this post](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/) (i.e. nicked most of the code).

I am also using DI via autofac so I have changed a few things around to inject dependencies into the `SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider`

**THE PROBLEM**
I post grant_type=password, username and password to `http://localhost/myappurl/token` and I get back "error":"invalid_client". I get no hits when I try to debug so its probably failing in the library and not getting to my own code. Does anyone know why this would be?

Please pardon the lengthy code, I have no idea where the issue could be so I have posted everything I think is relevant, if anyone needs to see more code, please ask.

**SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider**

```
 public class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }
    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {

        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

        var authenticate = await _userService.FindUser(context.UserName, context.Password);

            if (!authenticate)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));

        context.Validated(identity);

    }
}
```

**Startup**

```
public partial class Startup
{               
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        ConfigureOAuth(app, (IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider)config.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider)));
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }

    public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app, IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider provider)
    {
        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(90),
            Provider = provider,
            ApplicationCanDisplayErrors=true, 
        };
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

    }
}
```

**IocConfig**

```
public static class IocConfig
{

    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        // Configure the container 

        // Register individual components
        builder.Register(c => new MySQLContext()).As<IMySqlContext>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider>().As<IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider>();
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        var container = builder.Build();
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

    }
}
```

Comment: You should simplify your code to a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Perhaps remove the code for Autofac DI and see if that makes any difference. It's hard to tell what the problem might be otherwise.

Comment: Hi, yes indeed you were right @djikay, I removed all the DI stuff and I no longer get the error message, I wonder why though.....but that's one for me to investigate. If you could make your comment an answer and I'll accept it. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of code there, so it's not easy to isolate the problem. As a first step, consider removing the code for Autofac DI and see if that makes any difference. It's hard to tell what the problem might be otherwise.

If the issue is indeed related to the DI code, then perhaps this should be a raised as a separate question. In that case, try to create a small code example that demonstrates the issue succinctly. People are more likely to help if the problem code is short and to the point.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've set up SSL for your site. I had a similar issue and the problem was that I was not using SSL.